# injecting services into components

Tags: angular

I am new at angular, and I am running into this problem. I created a Postservice class which makes a http post request to some random api and returns a response. Also, in the PostService class I have an array which will hold all the response data object that comes in. I want to inject those responses into my post component class and display those responses in the html. However, when I try to inject PostService class into post component, and console.log the responses in my component class it says undefined. Can someone please help me?

PostService code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PostUser } from '../interface/postUser';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  items: Array<any> | undefined;

  base_uri = `https://reqres.in/api/users`;
  user = {
    id: 1,
    email: 'george.bluth@reqres.in',
    first_name: 'George',
    last_name: 'Bluth',
    avatar: 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg',
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  getRes() {
    this.http.post<PostUser>(this.base_uri, this.user).subscribe((data) => {
      this.items = [data];
    });
  }
}
```

Post Component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/services/post.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss'],
  providers: [PostService],
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}

  item: Array<any> | undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.item = this.postService.items;
    console.log(this.item);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is because the API call is asynchronous. Here your console.log() will execute before your API response comes. To overcome this, you could return an observable from service and subscribe it in your component and console within success call back function.

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet will help you.

Post Service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PostUser } from '../interface/postUser';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  base_uri = `https://reqres.in/api/users`;
  user = {
    id: 1,
    email: 'george.bluth@reqres.in',
    first_name: 'George',
    last_name: 'Bluth',
    avatar: 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg',
  };
  public getRes() {
    this.http.post<PostUser>(this.base_uri, this.user);
  }
}
```

Post Component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/services/post.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss'],
  providers: [PostService],
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}

  item: Array<any> | undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.item = this.postService.getRes().subscribe(response=>{
      console.log(response);
    }); 
  }
}
```

The process of making a http call is async and that is why the console.log the responses in component class is undefined. So, to get the value and if we to console.log the list, then do it inside the subscription.

Comment: Great to hear from you

Answer (score 0):

This is because the API call is asynchronous. Here your console.log() will execute before your API response comes. To overcome this, you could return an observable from service and subscribe it in your component and console within success call back function.

Below snippet will help you.

Service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  items=new BehaviourSubject<any>(null);

  base_uri = `https://reqres.in/api/users`;
  user = {
    id: 1,
    email: 'george.bluth@reqres.in',
    first_name: 'George',
    last_name: 'Bluth',
    avatar: 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg',
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  getRes() {
    this.http.post<PostUser>(this.base_uri, this.user).subscribe((data) => {
      this.items.next(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Post Component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/services/post.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss'],
  providers: [PostService],
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}

  items: Array<any> | undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postService.items.subscribe(response=>{
      console.log(response);
      this.items = response;
    }); 
  }
}
```